# C++ Asynchronous processing of large file

Tags: c++, asynchronous, parallel-processing

I have a large binary file that contains serialized Protocol Buffers, I can read the file message by message and de-serialize each message into a C++ object.

Now, each message must be processed by an algorithm, whose runtime heavily depends on the message, for some messages it's immediate, for some others can be "quite" long (i.e. 15x the time).

Since the execution time for each message is 'random', I believe that the best strategy is to use asynchronous programming. In particular I would like to read a chunk of the file (say 100 messages) and process those asynchronously, when the first thread finishes its jobs it goes on and reads the next chunk, when other threads finish their job they start to work as well on the newly read chunk. I cannot load in memory the whole file unfortunately.

I'm fairly new to distributed programming and never used async programming in C++ (only in Python), so I'm asking: is this the best strategy?

Another possible example showing the same behavior, is the following: suppose there is a file with one integer per line, I want to read the integers from the file and compute their factorials (in a stupid way):

```
int factorial(int n) {
  if (n <= 1) return 1;
  
  return n * factorial(n - 1);
}

std::vector<int> read_and_compute(std::string filename) {
  std::ifstream infile("thefile.txt");  
  std::string line;
  std::vector<int> out;
  while (std::getline(infile, line)) {
    std::istringstream iss(line);
    int n;
    if (!(iss >> n)) { break; } // error

    out.push_back(factorial(n));
  }
  return out;
}
```

This is an example of a sequential execution, how can I speed this up at best? I can use openmp, tbb and boost.

Comment: It's **a viable** strategy. Only you can decide if it's the best one.

Comment: How long is the longest process, as reading from a file is many orders of magnitude slower than your CPU?  The overall bottleneck might be reading the file and any processing time negligible - you need to measure before optimizing.

Comment: Processing the file, maybe. Reading and processing the file, probably not. Reading files is sssssslllllooooowwww and doing it in threads will just wind up with the threads wasting time fighting it out over access to the file.

Comment: @RichardCritten I would say that reading and deserializing from the file is ~ 10 faster than the _fastest_ process and ~ 150x faster than the _longest_ process

Comment: @mariob6 do those messages need to be processed in-order? I mean - do the results need to be in order in `out` in your example?

Comment: No, I think that random ordering is fine!

Comment: What you're suggesting sounds sensible to me, I would just avoid reading from the file from multiple threads (not sure if that's what you were suggesting or not). Instead just have one thread that reads from the file, and passes the messages to other threads for processing.

Comment: That sounds great, thanks everyone! Do you have any links / resources to get me started?

Comment: This sounds perfect for a Thread-Pool with a Job Queue. One thread reading the file and posting jobs to the queue and the rest of the threads in the pool pulling jobs one by one from the queue.  You can tune the process by increasing or decreasing the number of threads in the pool.